# Is there a cleaner method to pass a list of 10 or more values to a class and its function in python2.7 and execute them?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, class

Code Problem: Take userinput from a file and execute the class and its function line by line. The userinput will be like a list with 10 or more values. I have reduced the number of items for discussion purpose. I can make the code work and get the output but wondering if there is any cleaner method which can be scaled easily.

Note: **Python2.7** **cannot use 3.7 yet**

##Below is an example code and its output

\\

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age,club):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.club=club
    def get_club(self):
        if int(self.age)<10 and self.club=="lego":
            print("Student :"+self.name+' is in: '+self.club+ ' club')
        elif int(self.age)>15 and self.club=="football":
            print("Student :"+self.name+' is in: '+self.club+ ' club')
        else:
            print("Student :"+self.name+' is in: '+self.club+ ' club')
ui=[("Jim,8,lego"),("Dwight,16,football"),("Pam,21,arts")]
for i in ui:
    xy=i.split(',')
    c=student(xy[0],xy[1],xy[2])
    c.get_club()
```

\\

### Code Output

Student :Jim is in: lego club
Student :Dwight is in: football club
Student :Pam is in: arts club

Comment: What is the purpose of your if-statement? It seems to always return the same output

Comment: @JulienRoullé it's just an example code, i have not submitted the real math problem for ease of understanding.

Comment: @C.Nivs i see it works in python 3.7 , does it also work in 2.7 ? Note; I cannot upgrade to 3.7 yet as there are 100s of python file which needs upgrade slowly !

Comment: Instead of passing a preformatted list, you could pass a multi-line string (triple quote delimiter) and split by line endings first, which would result in a list similar to the one programmed here.  That is a good step forward toward being able to read the list from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example in python2, you'll want to use argument unpacking here.

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


a = range(2)
x = X(*a)

x.a
0
x.b
1
```

To show this for your specific example, I'm using `StringIO` to simulate a file:

```py
from StringIO import StringIO

ui=[("Jim,8,lego"),("Dwight,16,football"),("Pam,21,arts")]

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, club):
        self.name = name
        self.age = int(age)
        self.club = club

    def get_club(self):
        """
        You'll want to use string formatting here, it makes code much
        more readable, and allows the support of different formats
        """
        if self.age < 10 and self.club == "lego":
            print("Student : {} is in {} ".format(self.name, self.club))

        elif self.age > 15 and self.club == "football":
            print("Student : {} is in {} ".format(self.name, self.club))

        else:
            print("Student : {} is in {} ".format(self.name, self.club))


# you'll want to use `with open(file) as fh:` instead of
# this, which is just an example
fh = StringIO('\n'.join(ui))

for line in fh:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    # note the * here before the iterable
    c = Student(*line)
    c.get_club()

Student : Jim is in lego
Student : Dwight is in football
Student : Pam is in arts
```

`str.format` is portable from python2 to python3, and good on you for using the parentheses on `print`, that will make your eventual migration journey much easier